# Java customizable amount of nested for loops

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to make a customizable amount of nested for loops, something like this

```
int size=4;
for ...
  for ...
    for ...
      for ...
```

And when changing the size, creating a new nested loop

```
int size=6;
for ...
  for ...
    for ...
      for ...
        for ...
          for ...
```

I've been trying and testing and finally I got this:

```
    // The amount of nested loops
    int size=3;

    // Variables
    String output="";
    String code="";
    String home=new File("").getAbsolutePath();

    // Generating code

    // Opening
    code+="public class Temp { \n";
    code+="    public static void main(String[] args) { \n";

    String depth="        ";

    // Making the variables
    code+=depth+"int[] data = new int["+size+"];\n";
    code+=depth+"String output = \"\";\n";

    // Making the for loops
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        // Adding formatting
        for(int x=i; x>0; x--)
            code+="    ";

        // Creating for-loop
        code+=depth+"for (data["+i+"]=0; data["+i+"]<10; data["+i+"]++) {\n";
    }

    // Adding formatting
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
        code+="    ";

    // Making the output (data[0]+""+data[1]+""+data[2]+"" etc)
    code+=depth+"output+=";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        code+="data["+i+"]+\"\"";
        if(i<size-1)
            code+="+";
    }
    code+=";\n";

    // Adding formatting
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
        code+="    ";

    // Adding a newline after the output
    code+=depth+"output+=\"\\n\";\n";

    // Adding formatting and closing for-loops
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        for(int x=i; x<size-1; x++)
            code+="    ";
        code+=depth+"}\n";
    }

    // Outputting the variable output
    code+=depth+"System.out.println(output);\n";
    code+="    }\n";
    code+="}\n";

    // Outputting the code (for debugging purposes)
    System.out.println(code);

    // Compiling, running and getting output
    try {
        // Making a file called Temp.java
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("Temp.java");
        byte[] buf=code.getBytes();
        fos.write(buf);
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====");
        System.out.println("\n=====        Compiling        =====\n");

        // Executing
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -d "+home+" Temp.java");

        // Getting output and error
        InputStream is=p.getInputStream();
        InputStream es=p.getErrorStream();

        buf=new byte[8192];
        byte[] ebuf=new byte[8192];

        is.read(buf);
        es.read(ebuf);

        System.out.println(new String(buf).trim());
        System.err.println(new String(ebuf).trim());

        System.out.println("\n=====         Running         =====");

        // Executing
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Temp");

        // Getting output and error
        is=p.getInputStream();
        es=p.getErrorStream();

         buf=new byte[8192];
        ebuf=new byte[8192];
        is.read(buf);
        es.read(ebuf);

        // Make output the value of the external 'output'
        output=new String(buf).trim();
        System.err.println(new String(ebuf).trim());

        System.out.println("\n=====   Removing temp files   =====");

        // Executing
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -f Temp.java Temp.class");

        // Getting output and error
        is=p.getInputStream();
        es=p.getErrorStream();

        buf=new byte[8192];
        ebuf=new byte[8192];
        is.read(buf);
        es.read(ebuf);

        System.out.println(new String(buf).trim());
        System.err.println(new String(ebuf).trim());

        System.out.println("\n===== ===== ===== ===== ===== =====");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Outputting the output
    System.out.println("output\n"+output);
```

It works as it should, but I hate the way of creating, compiling and running an external Java file. Are there any better ways to do the same thing, without the use of an external file ?

Comment: Can't you put that `for` loop in another `for` loop?

Comment: @BhargavRao Which for loop in which for loop ? (:

Comment: @BhargavRao That's not nested

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, can be achieved trivially via recursion.

Comment: @axiom Explain in an answer, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either recursion is the answer (as stated above), or managing your "i" variables within an array instead:

```
public void nestedLoop(int size, int loopSize) {
    int[] i = new int[size];
    while (i[size-1] < loopSize) {
       doSomethingWith(i);
       increment(i, loopSize);
    }
}

public void increment(int[] i, int maxSize) {
   int idx = 0;
   while (idx < i.length) {
      if (++i[idx] < maxSize) {
         return;
      }
      i[idx++] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: `increment(i)` in `nestedLoop()` is not a function

Comment: Did you see the "increment" function in my answer?

Comment: Did you see that it is `increment(int[] i, int maxSize)` and not `increment(int[] i)` ?

Comment: It loops through using an "overflow" technique. You've basically asked how to count to x^y, where x is the loop size, and y is the number of loops. increment will "add one" to the number, keeping it in the base of the "x".

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem you have might be solved in several different ways, what follows is a generic answer.

Usually, whenever you have a situation in which the only way out seems to be writing a `meta-program` (i.e. code to generate code, happens frequently with people who are beginning programming), give **recursion** a thought.

**Example**

---

Consider the problem of generating all the possible strings of length `k` that can be created using the set `S = {a, b, c, d}`.

One way of doing it is to write a meta program, which generates another program having k `for` loops. Something like:

```
for `i1` in S:
    for `i2` in S:
    ...
       for `ik` in S:
           print i1 + i2 + ... + ik
```

You will then need to compile it and run the executable thus obtained using `system()` or a similar function.

A *much* cleaner alternative is to use recursion.

For eg:

```
//sg
public class printKStr
{
    int k;
    String S;
    public void printKdigs(int pos, char[] str) {
        if(pos == k) {
            System.out.println(str);
            return;
        }
        int l = S.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            str[pos] = S.charAt(i);
            printKdigs(pos + 1, str);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printKStr pk = new printKStr();
        pk.S = "abc";
        pk.k = 3;
        char[] temp1 = new char[pk.k + 1];
        pk.printKdigs(0, temp1);
    }

}
```

1. Each activation of `printKdigs` represents a for loop in some sense.
2. We need a data structure that can hold the state created by each of these activations, in this case, it is the `string` `str`.
3. We set values correctly and recurse. Finally, at the termination, the value in the data structures holding the trail of recursive calls (`str` here) gives you one legal combination.

Comment: @Charlie The answer is language agnostic.